# Service Fabric local cluster setup issue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am facing issue while connecting service fabric in my system after installing new version of service fabric - 3.2.

I have tried all the solutions available on internet.Also reinstall visual studio and service fabric.I have also make sure to ON the windows firewall.But still each time following error comes up while setting up.

> No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is
>   connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.

Anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling to solve this issue since last 4 days.I found the solution.

https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1060#issuecomment-425033033

I have shorten my computer name and it start working.